# Executable from py2exe stops running

Tags: python, scipy, py2exe

I'm trying to create a .exe from a python script using py2exe. After some tiresome research, I was able to run a functional .exe. However, I had to add a few more lines to my .py, including a new import.

My old imports are:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from scipy import signal
import pywt
```

and my old setup.py was:

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

excludes = []
includes = ["scipy.signal","scipy._lib.messagestream","scipy.spatial.transform._rotation_groups",
            "scipy.special.cython_special","pywt._extensions._cwt"]

opts = {
    "py2exe": {
        "includes":includes,
        "excludes":excludes
    }
}

setup(console=['Shweep.py'], options=opts)
```

I just added any includes that I could find from other related questions, and eventualy it worked.

My problem is with the new script. I have some new imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from scipy import signal
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import pywt
import math
```

and my setup.py runs, with warnings about missing modules (also had these the first time, although I'm not sure if they are the same). However, when I try to run the .exe using cmd, the program, after a few seconds, stops running, displaying a Just-In-Time Debug message, telling me to use Visual Studio to debug. When I try to run the same .exe on a different PC with Visual Studio, that message doesnt even show up.

Sorry if this is something simple, I'm a begginer on py2exe

**EDIT**: I tried to isolate parts of code to figure out what made the error.
It seems to be related to these two functions:

```
def filter_oximetry(x, t):
    """
    
    Filters a pulse oximetry signal for usage in the find_oximetry_events() function. 
    
    The signal is filtered through a 500th order FIR linear phase lowpass filter with a
    0,1 Hz cutoff frequency. All the values greater than the mean + 9 are replaced by 
    mean - 20 and those bellow mean - 9 are replaced with mean + 20 

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : List or numpy array.
        Oximetry signal.
    t : List or numpy array.
        Signal time.

    Returns
    -------
    y : List or numpy array.
        Filtered signal values.

    """
    
    # Calculating the sampling frequency
    fs = 1/(t[1] - t[0])
    
    # Lowpass linear phase FIR filter, designed through REMEZ.
    # 1500th order, with 0.1 Hz cutoff frequency and passband 
    # gain of 1.
    coef = signal.remez(numtaps = 500, bands = [0, 0.1, 0.2, fs/2], desired = [1, 0], Hz = fs, type = "bandpass")
    
    # Steady state initial conditions    
    zi = signal.lfilter_zi(coef, 1) 
    
    # Filtering the signal
    y, _ = signal.lfilter(coef, 1, x, zi = zi)
    
    # Compensating for a gain lower than 1 in the passband
    y += 6
    
    #Getting rid of spikes
    mean = y.mean()
    for n in range(1, len(y) - 1):
      if (y[n] >= mean + 9) or (y[n] <= mean - 9):
          
        # Interpolation
        y[n] = y[n - 1] - (y[n - 1] - y[n + 1] / 2) 
        
        # If it is still outside the limits...
        if (y[n] >= mean + 9): 
          y[n] = mean - 20
        
        # If it is still outside the limits...
        if (y[n] <= mean - 9): 
          y[n] = mean + 20
    
    return y

def filter_flow(x, flow_t):
    """
    
    Filters an oronasal thermistor signal for usage in the find_flow_events() function. 
    
    The signal is filtered through a 249th order FIR linear phase lowpass filter with a
    1 Hz cutoff frequency.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : List or numpy array.
        Oximetry signal.
    flow_t : List or numpy array.
        Signal time.

    Returns
    -------
    flow_y : List or numpy array.
        Filtered signal values.

    """

    # Calculating the sampling frequency
    fs = 1/(flow_t[1] - flow_t[0])
    
    # Lowpass linear phase FIR filter, designed through REMEZ.
    # 1500th order, with 0.9 Hz cutoff frequency and passband 
    # gain of 1.
    coef = signal.remez(249, [0, 1, 1.5, fs/2], [1, 0], Hz = fs, type = "bandpass")


    # Steady state initial conditions
    zi = signal.lfilter_zi(coef, 1) 
    
    # Filtering the signal
    flow_y, _ = signal.lfilter(coef, 1, x, zi = zi) 
    
    return flow_y
```

I still have no idea why it's not outputing any error messages. Also, it runs fine if I use spyder, but not when using the executable

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is your issue, you can check this post :

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67135887/pil-pillow-valueerror-py-spec-is-not-set/67785201#67785201)

Your solution :

I tested your script and i modified your setup.py and it's fonctionnal when i exclude few modules :

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(options = {
    "py2exe":
        {   
            "excludes": ["_pytest","qtpy"], 
        }
    },
      console=['Shweep.py'])
```

I exclude this modules because they create some issues.